Proof of Converse of Isosceles triangle using ASA
I'm trying to prove the converse of the isosceles triangle theorem. However, I am trying to prove it without using AAS, SSS or angle bisectors as all these theorems come after the converse of the isosceles in my textbook Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry, 3rd Edition by Greenberg. I am trying to use SAS or ASA and believe ASA could work but I am unsure how. Below is the converse I'm trying to prove.
Proposition 3.18: If in △ABC we have ∠B ≅ ∠ C, then AB ≅ AC and △ABC is isosceles.

Extend $AB$ to $D$ and $AC$ to $E$ such that $BD=CE$. Then $\triangle BCD\cong\triangle CBE$ by SAS. (You can also construct $D$ and $E$ such that $\angle BCD=\angle CBE$ and then use ASA. I just feel extend two segments by equal length is more natural)
Then we see that $\angle BCD=\angle CBE$ so $\angle ACD=\angle ABE$. Also, $BE=CD$ and $\angle D=\angle E$. By ASA, $\triangle ACD\cong\triangle ABE$. We are done.

I'm confused at how you came to the last bit △≅△

@myapepe Sorry I should be more specific. See my edits.

Thank you so much!
